# How do I upload applications to GitHub properly?

Tags: git, github

My applications are fine and dandy on my computer. Uploading them to GitHub works fine. But when I downloaded one of them from my repositories to see if everything is alright... They are empty.

1. I am starting a new project on GitHub.
2. I am opening GitBash in the file with my app.
3. git init
4. git add .
5. git commit -m"some stuff"
6. (Here I insert GitHub's generated command to link it to the repository)
7. git push -u origin master

Everything is cool, but when I download the application... It is all empty save for Main class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what did you commit?

Comment: How are you doing the downloading?

Comment: I am opening GitBash in the file with the app and commiting, well, finished app. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: I am picking Clone or Download and downloading ZIP.

Comment: opening GitBash in the file?

Comment: By "file with my app" do you mean directory? Does `git show --stat HEAD` after the commit list all the files you expected? Does github show the files you expected? What are you doing exactly when you "download the application"?

Comment: "File with my app" - I mean the location of my app on my disc (is it the directory?). 
The command: git show --stat HEAD - shows everything I'd like to see within the location of the application on my computer, but when done in a downloaded one, I can't make any commands. When I download an application from my GitHub, I literally place it anywhere and just open it with Intelij.

Comment: Sooo.... since GitBash shows me that everything is commited and fancy, I guess I am failing somewhere during the downloading process?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the repo to push to.

After git init

Run: git remote add origin linktorepo

Example,

```
git remote add origin myrepo.git
```

Comment: I am adding the repository (the line given to me by GitHub). GitBash pushes everything no problem and claims it's all fine. It says "fatal: remote origin already exists." :(

Comment: You get that when you run that line? Then it means that there is already a target push location. You can view what you origin you are pushing to by running git remote -v. If you are trying to change the location you can remove the old origin if it isn't the correct location with git remote remove origin.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new. :P Also, the files are present on my GitHub after all, I must be failing while downloading.

Comment: You may want to check what branch your are viewing when you are downloading from your repository on the GitHub website. If you are not on master you could try running git pull origin <branchname> But glad I could at least teach you something new.

Comment: Checked this too, I am on master. And thanks for yet another new thing learned. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, they either just appeared out of nowhere or I somehow managed to miss them. All the files are visibly available in my repository on GitHub, they just disappear when I download the app, so, obviously, I am failing somewhere along the downloading.

Thank you all for answers. :)